# Magento 2.4.1: Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\ProductFieldMapper does not exist

Tags: elasticsearch, magento-2.3

Upgraded Magento 2.3 to 2.4.1 recently. Everything seems fine with the website. When trying to login to Magento admin, below is what is displayed in the browser. Not sure what this means. Please advise as where to look for for a fix. Thanks

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\ProductFieldMapper does not exist

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\ProductFieldMapper does not exist
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:54]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:100]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/wyomind/framework/Helper/License.php:11]
#5 Wyomind\Framework\Helper\License->constructor() called at [vendor/wyomind/elasticsearchbrowser/Helper/Data.php:28]
#6 Wyomind\ElasticsearchBrowser\Helper\Data->__construct() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121]
#7 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:108]
#8 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#9 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/wyomind/framework/Helper/License.php:11]
#10 Wyomind\Framework\Helper\License->constructor() called at [vendor/wyomind/elasticsearchbrowser/Plugin/Ui/Config/Data.php:13]
#11 Wyomind\ElasticsearchBrowser\Plugin\Ui\Config\Data->__construct() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121]
#12 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:108]
#13 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#14 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php:174]
#15 Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList->getPlugin() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:133]
#16 Magento\Ui\Config\Data\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#17 Magento\Ui\Config\Data\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Ui/Config/Data/Interceptor.php:23]
#18 Magento\Ui\Config\Data\Interceptor->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Reader/UiComponent.php:100]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\UiComponent->interpret() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/ReaderPool.php:105]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ReaderPool->interpret() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Reader/Container.php:84]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Container->interpret() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/ReaderPool.php:105]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ReaderPool->interpret() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Reader/Body.php:68]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Reader\Body->interpret() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/ReaderPool.php:105]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ReaderPool->interpret() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:334]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:32]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]
#27 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:65]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:224]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:237]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->publicBuild() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:242]
#32 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult() called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:23]
#34 Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:120]
#35 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#36 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

Comment: You might have to install ElasticSearch on your server

Comment: I see that the vendor folder in Magento root has Elasticsearch, Elasticsearch6 and Elasticsearch7. Anything still wrong?

Comment: The path Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper exists, but not the specified  class ProductFieldMapper. Any suggestion as to what might be the issue.

Comment: elastic search installed Version: 7.10.1

Answer (score 0):

the issue seems to be with some 3rd party extensions.
kindly check if you have Amasty Layered Navigation,
if yes kindly try to disable extension Amasty_Shopby

```
bin/magento module:disable Amasty_Shopby
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

and run di:compile.
IF it helps you try to get an update from Amasty_Shopby for Magento2.4
kindly Accept as a Solution if this works for you and give Kudos Smiley Happy